# Is destination MAC address is always end point MAC address?

Tags: mac-address, networking

To simplify if the destination is on a separate network would the source still does ARP request or does it uses default GW's MAC as destination MAC?

Answer (score 1):

The destination MAC is always the next hop on that subnet, which may or not be the final endpoint. As you said, if the final destination is on another subnet, the sending device will use it's default gateway by putting the GW MAC as the Ethernet destination MAC address.